# jQuery - adding new div event listener

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically detect if a new `div` has been added to my page. Specifically, a `div`  or `font` with a certain class attached to it. This div is added during an ajax response from a php page, telling the user that a task completed or did not complete and has certain `.msgDivAuth` class attached to it for style.

The problem I'm having when the response comes back, is that it remains on the page; and you're left with a bunch of responses everywhere. So what I want to do is be able to fadeout, or clear the contents of these elements out after a six seconds they first appear on the page.

What I was thinking of doing is:

```
$(function(){
    $('font.msgDivAuth, div.msgDivAuth').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){

        alert("check");

    });
});
```

Now this will only check whether existing `.msgDivAuth` elements, on the page, have had their contents changed. But of course this does not account for a dynamic addition to the page returned by a successful ajax response.

In other words:

1. Check, in a dynamic fashion, for new content coming in.
2. Check if what came in has `.msgDivAuth` as a class attached to it.
3. If it does have a  `.msgDivAuth` class attached to it bet it, `div` or `font`, begin six second timer and fadeOut.
4. Existing `.msgDivAuth` `div` or `font` should also refresh their fadeout timers when their contents have been changed. (e.g. the function above).
5. Rinse and repeat.

I also need to mention that this script will be held in  `js` file along with other common functions that each page includes in its header.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: You should use $().on() and $().off() instead of .bind and .unbind. It is the preferred method of binding events since jquery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Totally agreed on that. I'm in the midst of migrating most of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the element by this function

use hideElement(element) function in your success callback

```
function hideElement(element) {
  var target = $(this).find('.msgDivAuth');
  target.hide()
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there are hundreds of success callbacks across the site and would be an impossible task to do this. I need something more general.

Comment: You can make it as a separate function and call in your success callbacks